# Luxor obelisk in Paris vs Luxor Las Vegas obelisk

Tags: paris, factoids, las-vegas

The [Luxor Obelisk in Las Vegas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxor_Las_Vegas) has Egyptian hieroglyphics on it as does the [Luxor Obelisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxor_Obelisk) in Paris. My question is...  are the hieroglyphics the same? Did they copy the Paris obelisk when building the Las Vegas one? And if they did that I wonder if that means it'd be the same height as well ?

My Google searches are inconclusive.

Comment: I looked in my "Egyptian Hieroglyphic Dictionary (Vol 1) Wallis Budge 1920" and it's really a short exercise to determine that the Vegas version is gibberish, at least for the period we're talking about. Example, the Paris version has lots of the bird looking left (phonetic [a] as a single symbol [kite]/[view]/[watch over]) and looking right is (phonetic [ti] as a single word [eagle]). The Vegas version has all the birds looking right, including the owl! Unintelligible, meaningless. At least according to my reference. When we stayed at the Vegas Luxor, I didn't look at it carefully though...

Comment: The owl looking left (Paris version) is phonetic [m]/[mm], [master] [god] [divine], the owl looking right (Vegas version) doesn't occur in my reference. Despite the glamour in both locations and their undisputed status as tourist *destinations*, I'm not sure it's really about travel in the way we define it, but will not post it to the review queue for courtesy to an established user.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about architecture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about classic Egyptian writing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's still about Egyptian hieroglyphics and not travel.